# don´t show image in admin site

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to show an image in the list display of the admin site.

```
def boton(self,obj):
    return mark_safe('<img src="file:///srv/www/project/static/admin/img/pdf.png" alt="PDF">')
```

Boton is in `list_display` in `admin.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just give paths to files on the disk of your server, you need to actually [serve the files through your webserver](http://book.seaside.st/book/advanced/deployment/deployment-apache/serving-files) and use django's [`django.contrib.staticfiles`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) to reference those files from within your application:

```
def boton(self,obj):
    return mark_safe('<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/img/pdf.png" alt="PDF">')
```

Comment: This is what i get now: http://mypage/admin/gestion/parte/%7B%7B%20STATIC_URL%20%7D%7Dadmin/img/pdf.png/
And don't show the image.
I have Ngingx and apache working correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try this will work as expected.

```
def image_data(self, obj):
    return mark_safe('<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}%s"alt="PDF" width=50 height=50>' %( str(obj.image_file) ))
```